# How to iterate over an array in an object with async pipe

Tags: angular, asynchronous, observable

I have an object literal `album$` that I get asynchronously into my component

```
album$: Observable<Album> = this._selectedAlbumSandbox.selectedAlbum$;
```

The `Album` interface looks as follow and as you see it has an array of `Image`.

```
export interface Album {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  caption: string;
  images: Image[];
}
```

Now, how can I loop over the `images` array in my template using an `async` pipe? Something like the following

```
 *ngFor="let image of album$.images | async"
```

Comment: What i used to d o if thats an option for you is to create a custom component where the list is given as an input parameter. That always works and is way cleaner to read in my opinion

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try this :

```
<li *ngFor="let image of (album$ | async)?.images">
 <h1>{{ image }}</h1>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you with safe navigation operator

```
<li *ngFor="let image of (album$ | async)?.images ">
  <h1>  {{ image }} </h1>
</li>
```